# Using a .NET Assembly in with DotNET.jl Julia

Tags: python, .net, .net-core, dll, julia

I am trying to use a .NET assembly from the Julia programming language. There is one package that supports this here: https://github.com/azurefx/DotNET.jl. The dll with types and methods that I want access to is here: https://github.com/nwamsley1/Thermo-DLLs. And there is more documentation here: https://github.com/thermofisherlsms/RawFileReader.

I can do this easily with python given the pythonnet package (https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) in the following example code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('./ThermoFisher.CommonCore.RawFileReader')
from ThermoFisher.CommonCore.RawFileReader import RawFileReaderAdapter
rawFile = RawFileReaderAdapter.FileFactory("./MA4358_FFPE_HPVpos_01_071522.raw")
print("Is Open? ", rawFile.IsOpen)
print("Is Error? ", rawFile.IsError)
##### output
Is Open?  True
Is Error?  False
```

This ThermoFisher.CommonCore.RawFileReader.dll allows access to large files of a proprietary ".raw" file format. Python is too slow to work with these data efficiently, so I would like easy access with Julia. Here is an attempted minimal example to do the same as the above but in Julia instead of Python (using the DotNET.jl package)

```
using DotNET
reader = T"System.Reflection.Assembly".LoadFrom(raw"./ThermoFisher.CommonCore.RawFileReader.dll")
rawfilereaderadapter = reader.GetType("ThermoFisher.CommonCore.RawFileReader.RawFileReaderAdapter", true, true)
filefactory = rawfilereaderadapter.GetMethod("FileFactory")
filepath = convert(CLRObject, "./MA4358_FFPE_HPVpos_01_071522.raw")
raw_file = filefactory.Invoke(filefactory, [filepath])
raw_file.IsOpen
raw_file.IsError
###### output
false
true
```

However if I enter raw_file.IsError or raw_file.IsOpen as in python, those return true and false respectively. There is an error opening the raw file and the raw file is not open. It took trail and error to get this far. Some observations.

1. filefactory.Invoke() takes two arguments as specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=net-7.0. However, the result is not sensitive to the first argument I provide to filefactory.Invoke(something, [filepath]). "something" can be anything and this still works, so long as something is there.
2. If instead of [filepath] I supply something that is not of type System.String, or if I supply more arguments `[filepath, someotherargument]` I get an error (in comments). That makes sense because the filefactory method accepts one argument of type System.String.

I am not getting any error message, but I am unable to access the .raw file as in python. However, I have clearly gotten somewhere because if I provide the wrong kind or number of arguments to the function there is an error. **Are there suggestions or comments as to what the problem is or how I might diagnose further?**

If it helps here is part of the .xml documentation for the dll

```
<member name="T:ThermoFisher.CommonCore.RawFileReader.RawFileReaderAdapter">
            <summary>
            This static class contains factories to open raw files
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:ThermoFisher.CommonCore.RawFileReader.RawFileReaderAdapter.FileFactory(System.String)">
            <summary>
            Create an IRawDataExtended interface to read data from a raw file
            </summary>
            <param name="fileName">File to open</param>
            <returns>Interface to read data from file</returns>
        </member>
```

Comment: error mentioned in 2). ``` CLRException: System.MissingMethodException: Method 'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke' not found.
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at CLRBridge.Meta.InvokeMember(IntPtr type, String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, IntPtr binder, IntPtr target, IntPtr[] providedArgs, UInt32 argCount, IntPtr& exception)
```

Comment: error continued 2) 
Stacktrace:
 [1] track_and_throw(exhandle::UInt64)
   @ DotNET.CLRBridge ~/.julia/packages/DotNET/Rx490/src/CLRBridge.jl:46
 [2] InvokeMember(type::UInt64, name::String, bindingFlags::UInt32, binder::Int64, target::UInt64, providedArgs::Vector{UInt64})
   @ DotNET.CLRBridge ~/.julia/packages/DotNET/Rx490/src/CLRBridge.jl:325

Comment: error continued 2) [3] invokemember(::UInt32, ::CLRObject, ::CLRObject, ::Symbol, ::CLRObject, ::Vararg{Any})
   @ DotNET ~/.julia/packages/DotNET/Rx490/src/marshalling.jl:83
 [4] invokemember(::CLRObject, ::CLRObject, ::Symbol, ::CLRObject, ::Vector{Int64})
   @ DotNET ~/.julia/packages/DotNET/Rx490/src/marshalling.jl:94
 [5] (::DotNET.PendingInvocation)(::CLRObject, ::Vararg{Any})
   @ DotNET ~/.julia/packages/DotNET/Rx490/src/operators.jl:19
 [6] top-level scope
   @ In[24]:6

Comment: I'm just guessing based on the docs, but why doesn't this work?
```
reader = T"System.Reflection.Assembly".LoadFrom(raw"./ThermoFisher.CommonCore.RawFileReader.dll")
T"ThermoFisher.CommonCore.RawFileReader.RawFileReaderAdapter".FileFactory("./MA4358_FFPE_HPVpos_01_071522.raw")
```

Comment: I suggest you use Python to read the file into a Pandas dataframe, export to CSV, and then read back to Julia.

Comment: Bill, I've ended up doing something similar. Am readining the data into the Parquet file format and then working with that.